Local vs system Java runtime Environment
I installed a local packaged called SerproID. It is a package for installing digital certificates.
It comes with its own Java runtime Environment. The command to run it is:
./jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.class=smartcert.LogConfig -classpath "lib/*" smartcert.Main

But it return the following error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Internal Error
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$5(GtkApplication.java:158)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:140)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more

If I run with the installed java (openjdk version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16, OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04), OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04, mixed mode, sharing)), I got instead:
Command: java -Djava.util.logging.config.class=smartcert.LogConfig -classpath "lib/*" smartcert.Main
Error:
Error: Could not find or load main class smartcert.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Any help is welcome.
